# jQuery, row click function, without last td click in this row

Tags: jquery

i write row click handler:

```
$('#mTable tr').unbind().live('click', function() {
     //specialFunction()
});
```

*specialFunction* must not reachable when i clicked on last `<td>` in clicked row.
is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### idea

You can bind it to *all td's except last*

#### solution

```
$('#myTable tr td:not(:last-child)'...
```

#### example

soon.